# Can we study invariance of field theories under local Lorentz transformations?

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Local internal symmetry transformations, where the group parameters are allowed to become functions of spacetime, has led to successful quantum field theories of electromagnetic, weak and strong interactions. Can we think of studying invariances of simple field theories by making Lorentz transformations "local"? I am interested in knowing what that would mean and whether such a conjecture is completely untenable. Please keep your discussion simple.

Comment: That would be equivalent to general covariance

Comment: Something like that would mean changing the frame differently at every spacetime point. Isn't it so?